# Xamarin Forms: getting a section of white space at the bottom of the screen

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am a newbie to the world of Xamarin and I am encountering a weird issue.  All of my screens have a Navigation bar at the bottom of the page and somehow a section of white space seems to appear beneath the navigation bar, like this:

[image]

This is a screenshot of the emulator and the blue section is the bottom of the navigation bar and the white space is the empty space I would like to remove.  Disregard the black section, with the buttons at the absolute bottom, that is just the emulator.

Essentially, I would like to make the Scroll go where this white space is.  As a side note, the navigation bar is added programmatically and the content immediately above the navigation bar is contained in a scrolling container.  Currently, I am getting this on a Galaxy android phone and an emulator set to "Android_Accelerated_Nougat".

What could this issue be?  What things can I check at possible suspects?  Are there any workarounds for this issue?

Update:

Here is the .xaml file:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<views:BaseContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:customRenderer="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.MyCustomRenderer;assembly=MyNamespace"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.Views;assembly=MyNamespace"
             x:Class="MyNamespace.Views.CompanyEditPage">
 <Grid >
    <Image Source="backgroundImg” Aspect="AspectFill" />
    <ActivityIndicator x:Name="actIndicator” VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Color="White" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
  <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Start">
    <ScrollView>\
      <StackLayout >        
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
          <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Start"
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        Orientation="Vertical"
                        Padding="20,10">
                        <Image x:Name="saveprofilebutton" Source="savebtn.png" Aspect="AspectFill" HeightRequest="40" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand">
              <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Save_OnTapped" />
              </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>
            <Image Source="companylogo.png"
                   HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
          </StackLayout>
          <BoxView BackgroundColor="#6182c6"
                   HeightRequest="1"/>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Start"
                          HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
          <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        Orientation="Horizontal"
                       Padding="50,0,40,0">
            <Label Text="Edit company membership"
                  TextColor="White"
                  FontSize="16"
                   HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
            <Image x:Name="companymembershipimg" Source="arrow.png"
                   HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" >
              <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="EditMembership_OnTapped"/>
              </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>
          </StackLayout>
          <BoxView BackgroundColor="#6182c6"
                   HeightRequest="1"/>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Start"
                           HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
          <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                       Orientation="Vertical"
                       Spacing="0">
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Start"
                     HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                     Orientation="Horizontal"
                         Padding="50,10,40,10">

              <Label  Text="Activity Start Date”
                    TextColor="White"
                    FontSize="16"
                     HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                      VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>

              <customRenderer:MyTimePicker x:Name="MyActivityStartTimePicker"
                                           Unfocused="ActivityStartTime_Unfocused"
                                           HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                                           VerticalOptions="Center"/>
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Start"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                         Padding="50,0,40,0">

              <Label  Text="Activity End Date”
                    TextColor="White"
                    FontSize="16"
                     HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
              <customRenderer:MyTimePicker x:Name="MyActivityEndTimePicker"
                                           Unfocused="ActivityEndTime_Unfocused"
                                           HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                                           VerticalOptions="Center"/>
            </StackLayout>
          </StackLayout>
          <BoxView BackgroundColor="#6182c6"
                   HeightRequest="1"/>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout>
          <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Start"
                                  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                 Orientation="Vertical"
                                 Spacing="10"
                                  Padding="50,20,40,20">              
        <Label >
              <Label.FormattedText>
                <FormattedString>
                  <Span Text="I want to update members every "
                        ForegroundColor="White"
                        FontSize="16" />
                  <Span x:Name="TimeRange”
                        Text="15"
                        ForegroundColor="White"
                       FontSize="16" />
                  <Span Text=" day(s)."
                        ForegroundColor="White"
                        FontSize="16" />
                </FormattedString>
              </Label.FormattedText>
            </Label>
            <customRenderer:MySlider x:Name="MySlider”
                                     Maximum="28"
                                     Minimum="1"
                                       ValueChanged="MySlider_OnValueChanged"
                                     Unfocused="MySlider_OnUnfocused"/>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                           HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                            Spacing="0" Margin="0" Padding="1" BackgroundColor="White">

              <Label x:Name="LblSunday” WidthRequest="36" TextColor="White" HeightRequest="28" FontSize="18" BackgroundColor="#00158f" Text="Su" Margin="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"  VerticalTextAlignment="Center">
                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                  <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Sunday_OnTapped" />
                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
              </Label>

              <Label x:Name="LblMonday” WidthRequest="36" HeightRequest="28" FontSize="18" BackgroundColor="#00158f" TextColor="White" Text="Mo" Margin="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"  VerticalTextAlignment="Center">
                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                  <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Monday_OnTapped"/>
                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
              </Label>

              <Label x:Name="LblTuesday” BackgroundColor="#00158f" WidthRequest="36" HeightRequest="28" FontSize="18" Text="Tu" Margin="1"  TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"  VerticalTextAlignment="Center">
                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                  <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Tuesday_OnTapped"/>
                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
              </Label>

              <Label x:Name="LblWednesday” BackgroundColor="#00158f" TextColor="White" WidthRequest="36" HeightRequest="28" FontSize="18" Text="We" Margin="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"  VerticalTextAlignment="Center">
                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                  <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Wednesday_OnTapped"/>
                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
              </Label>

              <Label x:Name="LblThursday” BackgroundColor="#00158f" WidthRequest="36" TextColor="White" HeightRequest="28" FontSize="18" Text="Th" Margin="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"  VerticalTextAlignment="Center">
                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                  <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Thursday_OnTapped" />
                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
              </Label>

              <Label x:Name="LblFriday” BackgroundColor="#00158f" TextColor="White" WidthRequest="36" HeightRequest="28" FontSize="18" Text="Fr" Margin="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"  VerticalTextAlignment="Center">
                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                  <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Friday_OnTapped" />
                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
              </Label>

              <Label x:Name="LblSaturday” BackgroundColor="White" Text="Sa"  WidthRequest="32" HeightRequest="28" FontSize="18" TextColor="#00158f" Margin="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"  VerticalTextAlignment="Center">
                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                  <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Saturday_OnTapped"/>
                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
              </Label>
            </StackLayout>
          </StackLayout>
          <BoxView BackgroundColor="#6182c6"
                   HeightRequest="1"/>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                     HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

          <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                       Orientation="Horizontal"
                       Padding="50,20,40,50">
            <Label Text="Activity List"
                   TextColor="White"
                   FontSize="16"
                   HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
            <Image x:Name="activityimg" Source="arrow.png"
                   HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" >
              <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="ActivityList_OnTapped"/>
              </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>
          </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
      </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
  </StackLayout>
</Grid>
</views:BaseContentPage>
```

Comment: We can only guess what the issue is without seeing your XAML. Please show at least one of your screens XAML or (even better) strip it down to a [mcve].

Comment: As mentioned before, we can only help if you share some code.

Comment: K. Will add it.

Comment: Where is your bottom navigation bar ?

Comment: It is added programmatically in code.